# GStreamer shmsink assertion 'segment->format == format' failed

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I have the following pipeline running from inside my program using OpenCV VideoWriter element.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! clockoverlay ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-size=2000000 name=/dev/shm wait-for-connection=false
```

When I consume the stream through the following pipeline everything works

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v shmsrc is-live=true socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-area-name=/dev/shm ! \
    "video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! \
    queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

but when I attempt to encode the stream in h264 with the following pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv shmsrc is-live=true socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-area-name=/dev/shm ! \
    "video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! \
    queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! \
    rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I get

`(gst-launch-1.0:8119): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed`

and I can't see anything from VLC. What am I missing?

**Note**: To reproduce the problem one can use the following producer/consumer pipelines:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! clockoverlay ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-size=2000000 name=/dev/shm wait-for-connection=false
```

```sh
sudo gst-launch-1.0 -vvv shmsrc is-live=true socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-area-name=/dev/shm ! \
    "video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! \
    queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

#### System information

- Ubuntu 16.04
- GStreamer 1.8.3
- OpenCV 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found [this](https://mazdermind.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/getting-shmsinkshmsrc-to-work-with-videomixer/) article which helped me solve the problem.

My final pipelines look as follows.

#### Producer pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc is-live=true ! clockoverlay ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-size=2000000 name=/dev/shm sync=true wait-for-connection=false
```

#### Consumer pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv shmsrc is-live=true do-timestamp=true socket-path=/tmp/sink shm-area-name=/dev/shm ! \
    "video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! \
    queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.200.255 port=5000 sync=false
```